# Error running Express.js on Nuxt3 server/middleware

Tags: nuxt3

I get an error when I run Express.js on Nuxt3 server/middleware.

// Error
`TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'content-type')`

I want to do the csrf check on Nuxt3/server/muddleware, but I am having trouble because of this above error.

How do I migrate this code from express to h3?

```
import express from "express";
import csurf from 'csurf'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
 
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.raw())
app.use(express.text())
app.use(cookieParser())
const csrf = csurf({ cookie: false })
 
const csurfProtection = (req, res, next) => {
  return csrf(req, res, next)
}
app.use(csurfProtection)
app.use("/", router);

export default fromNodeMiddleware(app);
```

I am hoping the change to h3 will work the same way.